# i'm not able to see theservice bus feature in wso2 api manager analytics

Tags: wso2, servicebus, api-manager

Iam not able to see the service bus features like API,sequences and inbound end points etc...
may i know the reason why its happening like that?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWemm.png)

Thanks and regards 
sai kumar

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please review: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Only the required features to run analytics are installed on API manager analytics server.

If you want to use API, sequences and inbound endpoints you should use a wso2ei server.